# What am I doing wrong in ursina first person controller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-engine

I'm following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHSRaVeQxIk

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong at the 22:14 mark. The floor he made is flat and together, mine is tilted 90 degrees.

The engine is pretty new and I can't add a tag for Ursina so I apologize if I'm tagging different tags.

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,
            medel = 'cube',
            origin_y = 0.5,
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.white,
            highlight_color = color.lime)

app = Ursina()

for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (x,0,z))
player = FirstPersonController()

app.run()
```

Comment: You misspelled `model` as `medel`.

Answer (score 2):

If you fix your 'medel' property to the correct spelling 'model', it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```py
for z in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        voxel = Voxel(position = Vec3(x,0,z))
player = FirstPersonController()
```

You need to complete your code with Vector3